# Fatal signal 11 android Visualizer

Tags: android, fatal-error, visualizer

I'm developing application that play a list of audio files after click of button play all, after playing each file I recreate a new VisualizerView from https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer 
Problem: some times I get this nasty Fatal error 11 I can't figure out the pattern sometimes after second item some times it playing well 40 items without the problem.

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),
                    afd.getLength());
afd.close();
showVisualizer(mMediaPlayer);
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.start();

public void showVisualizer(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (!mShowVisualizer) {
        return;
    }
    //add new
    mVisualizerView = new VisualizerView(this);
    mVisualizerView.link(mp);
    mFrameVisualizer.addView(mVisualizerView);
    mFrameVisualizer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (visualizerType.equals(getString(R.string.visualizer_line))) {
        addLineRenderer(mVisualizerView);
    } else if (visualizerType.equals(getString(R.string.visualizer_bar))) {
        addBarGraphRenderers(mVisualizerView);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unrecognized renderer");
    }
}

    public void hideVisualizer() {
    if (mFrameVisualizer.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
        mFrameVisualizer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d(TAG, mVisualizerView + " mVis vuew");
        if (mVisualizerView != null) {
            mFrameVisualizer.removeView(mVisualizerView);
            mVisualizerView.release();
            Log.d(TAG, mVisualizerView + " mVisualizerView released");
            mVisualizerView = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Updated: 
Stacktrace:

```
    01-13 21:21:56.416 30943   847 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x44a00000 (code=2), thread 847 (Visualizer)
    01-13 21:21:56.471  2577  2577 I DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    01-13 21:21:56.471  2577  2577 I DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/m0xx/m0:4.1.2/JZO54K/I9300XXELLA:user/release-keys'
    01-13 21:21:56.471  2577  2577 I DEBUG   : pid: 30943, tid: 847, name: Visualizer  >>> com.iq.android <<<
    01-13 21:21:56.471  2577  2577 I DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 44a00000
    01-13 21:21:56.951  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     r0 5ae37ed0  r1 00010000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
    01-13 21:21:56.951  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     r4 44a00000  r5 60ecde48  r6 40bb4f54  r7 60ecde50
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     r8 5ae37ed0  r9 60ecde20  sl 40125a6c  fp 00000001
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     ip 40bb6bb0  sp 60ecde00  lr 40b8ac2d  pc 44a00000  cpsr 40000010
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d0  000000c843480000  d1  0000000043480000
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d2  0000000000000000  d3  44a0000000000000
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d4  0000009200000000  d5  44a0000044340000
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d6  449fe0004433c000  d7  0000000000000000
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d8  0000000043020000  d9  0000000000000000
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d16 7fffffffffffffff  d17 7fffffffffffffff
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d18 0000000000000000  d19 20000008409dbe40
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d20 3ffe000000000000  d21 3fee000000000000
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d22 0000000000000000  d23 3fee000000000000
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
    01-13 21:21:56.956  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
    01-13 21:21:56.961  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
    01-13 21:21:56.961  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    01-13 21:21:56.961  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     scr 20000013
    01-13 21:21:56.966  2577  2577 I DEBUG   : 
    01-13 21:21:56.966  2577  2577 I DEBUG   : backtrace:
    01-13 21:21:56.966  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     #00  pc 01b26000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap         (deleted)
    01-13 21:21:56.966  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     #01  pc 0005ec2b  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::Visualizer::getWaveForm(unsigned char*)+36)
    01-13 21:21:56.966  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     #02  pc 0005edf9  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::Visualizer::periodicCapture()+80)
    01-13 21:21:56.966  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     #03  pc 0005ee87  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::Visualizer::CaptureThread::threadLoop()+14)
    01-13 21:21:56.966  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     #04  pc 0001104f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
    01-13 21:21:56.966  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     #05  pc 0004bc2b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
    01-13 21:21:56.966  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     #06  pc 00010bb5  /system/lib/libutils.so
    01-13 21:21:56.971  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     #07  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so         (__thread_entry+48)
    01-13 21:21:56.971  2577  2577 I DEBUG   :     #08  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Does it produce a stacktrace? If so please post it.

Comment: I getting this on JB whereas I didn't get it on 2.3 is there a solution anywhere?

Comment: Mike what device do you use? I suppose that it is problem of Samsung because I can't reproduce it on Nexus 7 or Nexus S with JB

Comment: I reduced the occurrence of the error by setting a fixed id to my mediaplayer when recreating it. This way I can reuse the old visualiser without recreating it. Anyway, did you find a better solution?

Comment: No, I haven't found any better solution :(

Comment: Any updates on this topic? I'm having similar the same problem and it's starting to piss me off .... ! :(

Comment: @AndreiBogdan finished that project long time ago. Haven't found proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. I am creating a new AudioTrack and constructing a new Visualizer based on the session id every time a new file is opened. Getting Fatal signal 11 and 6 at random times shortly after Visualizer construction on a Nexus 7 with 4.4.2, but not an HTC One GPE w/ 4.4.2.

Ugly and inexplicable as it is, what fixed it for me was:

```
Thread.sleep(100)
```

before construction of the new Visualizer but after the AudioTrack is initialized (and release() of the previous Visualizer).
I welcome a better solution.

Comment: Tried this, does not help

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty late but I came over this issue now.
My solution was to release the visualizer everytime before enabling it.

*** Edit ***
Some further testing showed that the issue still appear - sorry

Comment: Any solution for it? I'm having the same issue :(